# change specific field of an object using POST method django rest api

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

i'm using djangorestframework. and i want to be able to change specific field of my objects using POST method. can anybody help please?? i have no idea how to do that.
here is my model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    national_code = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    personal_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    married = models.BooleanField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    wage = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

and I want to be able to for example change one of my employee's wage(with personal code 123)to new wage 500000 using such url:

```
POST /myupdate/123/500000
```

Comment: It's not recommended to send your data over url like your wage and it's better to send it as data in your request. And also for updating you must use put or patch not post.

Comment: @Mastisa yes exactly. all the examples i saw was with patch or put. but in my project it specifically asks to use post method with this url.is that even possible to do that??

Comment: It's possible to do anything with http methods, but some how it's against rules.

Comment: @Mastisa right.by the way thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Let's have quick example:

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

serializers.py

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    first_name = serializer.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    last_name = serializer.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

views.py

```
class UpdateEmployeeView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    model = Employee

    def put(self, request, id):
        try:
            instance = self.model.objects.get(id=id)
            serialized_data = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data)
            if serialized_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                self.perform_update(serialized_data)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(serialized_data.data), content_type="application/json")
        except ValidationError as e:
                return HttpResponse(e.detail, status=400, content_type="application/json")

    def patch(self, request, id):
        try:
            instance = self.model.objects.get(id=id)
            serialized_data = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serialized_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                self.perform_update(serialized_data)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(serialized_data.data), content_type="application/json")
        except ValidationError as e:
                return HttpResponse(e.detail, status=400, content_type="application/json")
```

urls.py

```
path('employee/<int:id>/', UpdateEmployeeView.as_view())
```